# Proving equivalence of statements about group cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing

I found the following statement with regards to group cosets:

> Let $H$ be a subgroup of a group $G$ and suppose that $a, b \in G$.
>
> If $aH = bH$, then $b \in aH$.

My attempt at writing a proof:

Assume $aH = bH$, then for some $h \in H$ we find $b \circ h = b$, thus $b \in bH$.

But $bH = aH$, therefore $b \in aH$ is also true.

My question: Is the reverse also true? Meaning, if $b \in aH$, then $aH = bH$? In other words, can we create an iff statement?

I tried to show that if $b \in aH$, then $aH = bH$, but didn't get very far.

EDIT: Is it possible to show the iff is true without using equivalence relations?

Comment: "for some $h \in H$ we find $bh = b$". You can be more specific than this. What element $h$ satisfies $bh = b$?

Comment: @Bungo true, it must be that $h=e$ the identity element of $G$. And since $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, $e \in H$.

Comment: Yes, the converse is also true. Every element of $G$ is contained in exactly one coset of $H$. Clearly $b \in bH$. If also $b \in aH$, then because there's only one coset containing $b$, this forces $aH = bH$. Thus the coset containing $b$ has (at least) two names: $aH$ and $bH$.

Comment: Correct, $e \in H$, hence $b = be \in bH = aH$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because coset membership is an equivalence relation then cosets are either disjoint or identical, therefore the converse will also be true.  Therefore an iff statement is possible.

Your proof is a little clunky.  Notice that since $aH = bH$ then we have $a^{-1}bH = H$ hence we can write $a^{-1}b = h \in H$.  What does this tell you about $b$?

For the converse, $b \in aH$ implies that $bH \subseteq aH$, since for any $h, h' \in H$ we have $b = ah$ and therefore $bh' = ahh'$, so $bh' \in aH$.  What does this tell you about the element $a$?

Comment: Is it possible to show the iff is true without using equivalence relations?

Comment: @max Yes, it is possible.  See my edits above.

Comment: Thanks for your update. So $b=ah$ makes sense, for some $h \in H$. Then $a = bh^{-1}$ and $a \in bH$. Is that right?

Comment: Assuming I'm not way off: Then $a \in bH$ implies $aH \subseteq bH$ and since $bH \subseteq aH$, this would imply $aH = bH$.

Comment: @Max Yes, you got it.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, that was super useful.